# Not able to import pikepdf after having successfully installed it in my virtual environment

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, pikepdf

I installed pikepdf in my virtual environment in my anaconda prompt. However, when I try to import it in my Jupyter notebook, it says "no module named 'pikepdf'".

I tried upgrading my pip, close and reopen my Jupyter, but nothing seems to work.

Is there someone who could help me?

Thank you

Comment: You sure you selected the right interpreter in Settings? You need to use the one from the venv not your system interpretor or other

Answer (score -1):

If you are on linux run this command in the shell:

```
pip3 install pikepdf
python3
```

If you are on windows run:

```
pip3 install pikepdf
python
```

and in the python console import the library using:

```
import pikepdf
```

If you get any error post it. If you don't get any error try to run your program from the CMD/shell with, on linux:

```
python3 your_program.py
```

on windows:

```
python your_program.py
```